# Need help troubleshooting Google App Engine job that worked in dev but not production

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have been working on a website for over a year now, using Django and Python3 primarily. A few of my buddies and I built a front end where a user enters some parameters and submits, this goes to the GAE to run the job and return the results.

In my local dev environment, everything works well. I have two separate dev environments.  One builds the entire service up in a docker container.  This produces the desired results in roughly 11 seconds. The other environment runs the source files locally on my computer and connects to the Postgres database hosted in Google Cloud. The Python application runs locally.  It takes roughly 2 minutes for it to run locally, a lot of latency between the cloud and the post/gets from my local machine.

Once I perform the Gcloud app deploy and attempt to run in production, it never finishes.  I have some print statements built into the code, I know it gets to the part where the submitted parameters go to the Python code. I monitor via this command on my local computer: `gcloud app logs read`.

I suspect that since my local computer is a beast (i7-7770 processor with 64 GB of RAM), it runs the whole thing no problem.  But in the GAE, I don't think it's providing the proper machines to do the job efficiently (not enough compute, not enough RAM).  That's my guess.

So, I need help in how to troubleshoot this.  I tried changing my app.yaml file so that resources would scale to 16 GB of memory, but it would never deploy.  I received an error 13.

One other note, after it spins around trying to run the job for 60 minutes, the website crashes and displays this message:

> 502 Server Error
>   Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: A couple of things: (1) are you sure the deploy was successful i.e. that all files were copied in their correct state? (2) Can you just extend your print statements to be added at various points until the end of the job? That feels like a good debugging technique, and just needs to be extended to cover the point of the crash.

Comment: I double checked the files, they copied correctly.  I have added additional print statements to track the progress as it executes.  I think the job is too CPU and memory intensive so I have re-writtent the code to optimize a bit more.  If it works, I'll comment back.

Comment: Did you narrow down the point(s) at which execution stops using the print statements?

Comment: Yes. A few things learned here.  1. Don't use the Pandas package in production.  2.  Print statements for debugging purposes is the bomb-diggity.  3.  I learned that I needed to specify "instance_class: F4_1G" in the app.yaml file to get an instance with more memory.

Comment: Great, is that an answer? It can go below as a self-answer, if that would help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so just in case anybody in the future is having a similar problem...the constant crashing of my Google App Engine workers was because of using Pandas dataframes in the production environment.  I don't know exactly what Pandas was doing, but I kept getting Memory Errors, it would crash the site...and it didn't appear to be occurring in a single line of code.  That is, it randomly happened somewhere in a Pandas Dataframe operation.

I  am still using a Pandas Dataframe simply to read in a csv file.  I then use

```
data_I_care_about = dict(zip(df.col1, df.col2)) 
#or 
other_data = df.col3.values.tolist()
```

and then go to town with processing.  As a note, on my local machine (my development environment basically) - it took 6 seconds to run from start to finish .  That's a long time for a web request but I was in a hurry, thus why I used Pandas to begin with.

After refactoring, the same job completed in roughly 200ms using python lists and dicts (again, in my dev environment).  The website is up and running very smoothly now.  It takes a maximum of 7 seconds after pressing "Submit" for the back-end to return the data sets and render on the web page.  Thanks for the help peeps!